# C# подключение com объекта

Tags: c#, com

Как подключить com объект написанный на c++, к С# проекту?

Answer (score 1):

Правой кнопкой по проекту -> Add Referense вкладка COM

Comment: В реестре есть этот объект и к C++ подключается, а в C#, в Referense его нет.

Answer (score 0):

Что за объект? Если интерфейс, то тебе надо найти от него `*.tlb` файл, натравить на него tlbimp.exe из командной строки Visual Studio - оно тебе создаст dll-ку с четырьмя объектами: 2 интерфейса и 2 класса. Потом эту dll-ку уже к проекту подцепляешь (у меня почему-то получалось использовать из нее только интерфейс `*Ctrl` - но может так и должно быть, в подробности не вникал)