# C# и COM обьект

Tags: c#, com

Первый раз использую ком обьекты. Подскажите пожалуйста, я зарегистрировал ком объект, теперь хочу проверить его работоспособность, методом тыка, создав консольное приложение в студии, я пытаюсь добавить ссылку на этот ком обьект и в отчет получаю ошибку, почему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# подключение com объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215594/c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-com-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @Yami вы считаете там описана аналогичная проблема?

Comment: @Winteriscoming скомпилируйте Release, и её подключайте

Comment: @Yami ни разу не дубликат, языки-то разные...

Comment: @DigitalCore подскажите должны ли `Guid` в коде отличатся у интерфейса и класса, который его реализует?

Comment: @Winteriscoming ну разумеется должны

Answer (score 2):

В .NET нет способа использовать управляемый объект как COM-объект, при передаче в управляемую среду все управляемые COM-объекты автоматически "распаковываются". А эта распаковка означает, в том числе, что он будет реализовывать только интерфейсы из своей сборки, а не импортированные вами. Именно об этом и предупреждает вас студия.

Если вам нужно проверить ваш управляемый COM-объект - попробуйте создать неуправляемое приложение. Например, подойдет консольное приложение на языке C++.

Comment: Можете подробнее объяснить, пожалуйста, будут ли отличаться COM-объекты, написанные в среде .NET и на C++? Если да, то чем именно? Пытаюсь осмыслить для себя, что значит `управляемые COM-объекты` и существуют ли неуправляемые в таком случае.

Comment: С точки зрения плюсового кода они никак не отличаются. С точки зрения CLR они отличаются тем, что являются "родными" и взаимодействие с ними идёт мимо механизмов COM.